# TypeError: expect.createSpy is not a function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Trying to use properties of spy and end up with this error.

```js
var spy = expect.createSpy();
spy();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Error :

```
TypeError: expect.createSpy is not a function
```

Comment: What is `expect`?

Comment: find it from here : http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/

Comment: I am having the issue with : https://github.com/mjackson/expect/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chai` doesn't offer spies, for that you need a library like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/).

There's a Chai plugin called [`sinon-chai`](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai) that creates a useful combination of the two:

```
const chai      = require('chai');
const sinon     = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const expect    = chai.expect;

chai.use(sinonChai);

// Create the spy, using Sinon.
let spy = sinon.spy();

// Call the spy, so we can test it.
spy();

// Assert that the spy has been called.
expect(spy).to.have.been.called;
```

Answer (score 3):

Which version of `expect` you are running? as per GitHub page, `expect` has been donated to Jest

If you are running v21+ then you will have to use Jest mock functions `jest.fn()` instead of the normal `expect.createSpy()`

Follow installation steps @[here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html) then use the following code and you should be fine.

```
var spy = jest.fn();
spy();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: I hate commenting on an older post, but this came up high on the list for a Google search.  Be sure to require jest-mock (not just jest) for this code to work.

Answer (score -2):

Try downgrading the **expect** library version to **@1.20.2** and it should work